# What is the type of p in {int (*(*(*p(int x))())[20])(int *y);}

Tags: c

`int (*(*(*p(int x))())[20])(int *y);` 
What is the type of p?
And how to figure out similar complex declaration in C?

Comment: https://cdecl.org/ is your friend, but even it chokes on that abomination.

Comment: @Shawn: No, it does not, it simply does not support named parameters, even in simple declarations like `int foo(int bar)`. Deleting the `x` and the `y` yields a result.

Comment: The type of `p` in `int (*(*(*p(int x))())[20])(int *y)` is `int (*(*(*(int))())[20])(int*)`.

Comment: "how to figure out similar complex declaration in C?" Don't. Make sure that the person who wrote the code gets fired, then rewrite it from scratch. Code like this isn't a programming problem - it's a programming puzzle at best.

Comment: If this is real world code from a real world project then someone needs to get their keyboard removed

Answer (score 6):

You start from the variable name, then proceed outwards, first consuming things on the right, then things on the left, unless parentheses force a different order.

```
          p                          // `p` is
          p(int x)                   // a function with parameter `int x`, returning
         *p(int x)                   // a pointer to
        (*p(int x))                  // ...
        (*p(int x))()                // a function with unspecified parameters (or no parameters in C++), returning
       *(*p(int x))()                // a pointer to
      (*(*p(int x))())               // ...
      (*(*p(int x))())[20]           // an array of size 20 of
     *(*(*p(int x))())[20]           // pointers to
    (*(*(*p(int x))())[20])          // ...
    (*(*(*p(int x))())[20])(int *y)  // a function with parameter `int *y`, returning
int (*(*(*p(int x))())[20])(int *y)  // int
```